# "Bi-singleton" pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I know how the singleton pattern works in java, but I'd like to adapt it to make it possible to create 2 instances of this class and not just one. I've been thinking about this, maybe using an instance counter, but nothing satisfying has come out so far.

Comment: The best solution is using java enums. Actually singletons are better implemented as enums as well.

Comment: @tsolakp what is wrong with setting the constructor(s) of a class private and initialize one `public static final INSTANCE` on class-level to realize a Singleton?

Comment: The duplicate answer does not look like the best solution to the OP question.

Comment: @Turin85. See: Item 3 of Effective Java 2nd --  Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an enum type.

Comment: The best solution is to just make it a normal class... Not a singleton, or a bi-singleton, or anything like that.